# linkedin app verification status shows Review in Progress

Tags: linkedin-api

we applied for marketing developer platform product permission 40 days back, and still our application status is shown as "Review in progress".

We need to be able to read company page feed. That is all we need the API for.

Our app used to work before their API changed couple of months back. 
Could anyone please share how to read LinkedIn company page feed or how the review process works with LinkedIn please?

Comment: We're in the exact same situation as you (just need to post to the company page) and have been waiting 79 days 

Comment: that sounds not good and scary. all we need is to read company page activity feed.

Comment: We were finally approved! I can't promise it will help, but we seem to have been able to expedite our application by submitting a message to the [LinkedIn Developer Helpdesk](https://linkedin.zendesk.com/hc/en-us). We reiterated that our use case was super simple and kindly asked for help. Hopefully you will have a similar experience!